# How to prevent render method from throwing error on a state that is initially set to undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render my state which updates by pulling data from an api so the initial value of the state is undefined. I am receiving the error *TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.Pods[0].Name')*. From what I understand about react, every time the state is updated the components that use that state re-renders, so the text that initially was undefined will then render the updated state value. My question is could you bypass the initial error from being thrown so it can render the value of state when its updated. Here's how im calling the state:

```
<Text>{this.state.Pods[0].Name}</Text>
```

Ive tried using getDerivedStateFromError but I it isn't working for me.

```
static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        return { hasError: true };
      }

 render() {
        if (this.state.hasError) {
            return <Text>Something went Wrong</Text>
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, verify it before you do anything.

So verify if `this.state.Pods` is there and `this.state.Pods[0]` is there.

**Having said that, directly accessing an index and then only using that single one, begs the question, why would you need an array?**

So, you can first verify if `this.state.hasError` is true, then return the error message, if it's not true, and you don't have the pods yet, then return null, otherwise return your actual render, like:

```
render() {
  const { hasError, Pods = [] } = this.state;
  if (hasError) {
    return <div>Error occured</div>;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(Pods) || !Pods[0]) {
    return null;
  }
  return <Text>{Pods[0].Name}</Text>;
}
```

When the state gets updated, your component will rerender and it will again check all the conditions, giving you either an error, again null (if Pods is not there yet or not what you expect it to be) or it will render your text element

Comment: @Sayu Happy it did, please note that I also asked a question for you to think of (why do you need it to be an array if you are only accessing a direct index). If it worked, feel free to mark it as answered

Answer (score 2):

Please use this

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.Pods || !this.state.Pods[0] )  {
        return <Text>Loading</Text>
    }
```

Comment: Yours worked too but the other person had a better explanation. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way of using error boundary component. if you are expected

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

In your component.

```
render() {
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <Text>{this.state.Pods[0].Name}</Text>
  </ErrorBoundary>
}
```

though you don't need error boundry in your case.
you should read your state safely as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your code as below.

```
<Text>{Array.isArray(this.state.Pods) && this.state.Pods.length > 0 && this.state.Pods[0].Name}</Text>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using constructor or instance variable like:

```
class A extends React.Component {
    state = {
        Pods: []
    }
}
```

OR

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            Pods: []
        }
    }
}
```

This way your state will have a value intially, now inside `render` you can check if your data from the API has arrived:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.Pods.length) {
        return <div>{this.state.Pods}</div>
    }
    return ''
}
```

Comment: it's not recommended to return undefined implicitly (which would happen in your suggested render)